# CSS - centering horizontally and pushing an element down with pure css

Tags: html, css

Alright, so i have an element with the class called `.price` within the element `.item` as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgXCr.png). Now what I want is to have `.price` centered horizontally and it being pushed/pulled to the bottom border of its parent, [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6m7kr.png).

now here comes the fun part which makes this hard:

- pure css (no javascript/jquery)
- it needs to be dynamic, so the `width`/`height` property of `.price` can fluctuate (see snippet)

here's how far i got:

```css
.item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px; /* not static */
  background: wheat;
}
.product-image {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 180px;
  height: 300px;
  background: lightskyblue;
}
.price {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50px; /* not static */
  height: 20px; /* not static */
  background: indianred;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="product-image">
  </div>

  <div class="price">
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with `flexbox`.

**Steps:**

1. Set your `.item` element as a flex-container with `display: flex;` and change its direction using `flex-direction: column;`
2. Since your `flex-direction` is set to `column`, you can use `align-self: center;` to horizontally center your `.price` element (now a flex-item), and finally use `margin-top: auto;` to position it to the bottom.

```css
.item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  /* not static */
  background: wheat;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.product-image {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 180px;
  height: 300px;
  background: lightskyblue;
}
.price {
  align-self: center;
  margin-top: auto;
  width: 50px;
  /* not static */
  height: 20px;
  /* not static */
  background: indianred;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="product-image">
  </div>

  <div class="price">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go

```css
.item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  /* not static */
  background: wheat;
  position: relative;
}
.product-image {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 180px;
  height: 300px;
  background: lightskyblue;
}
.price {
  width: 50px;
  /* not static */
  height: 20px;
  /* not static */
  background: indianred;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="product-image">
  </div>

  <div class="price">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually this fix the element at the bottom of the offset not inside the item div.

Answer (score 0):

You should use relative positioning for your parent div and absolute in child divs.

[My example](http://plnkr.co/edit/sT7Y0JcMhBTvhYBY99tJ?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="product-image"> </div>

    <div class="price">
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>

</html>

.item {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px; /* not static */
  background: wheat;
  position:relative;
}
.product-image {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background: lightskyblue;
}
.price {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50px; /* not static */
  height: 20px; /* not static */
  background: indianred;
  position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Relative positioning on the parent container (item) and absolute positioning on the child containers.

```css
.item {
   width: 200px;
   height: 400px; /* not static */
   background: wheat;
 position: relative;
}
.product-image {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 90%;
   height: 75%;
   background: lightskyblue;
}
.price {
   margin: auto 39%;
   width: 25%; /* not static */
   height: 5%; /* not static */
   background: indianred;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 3%; 
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
   <div class="product-image">
    </div>
   
    <div class="price">
   </div>
</div>
```

Or instead of setting the margin you could just use the left or right properties of positioning to move it center. If you want price to be flush with the bottom just change the bottom percentage to '0'.

The other idea that comes to mind is creating another div container just for price and relatively positioning it at the bottom of your parent container, absolutely positioning the price div and than simply using text-align in the parent. Although I haven't actually tried this yet.